# Is there any way to add tab layout without letting the activity to extend TabActivity?

Tags: android

I want to add tabs to the layout of my activity, but I don't want the activity to extend TabActivity. The example in http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html only gave example of subclass of TabActivity.

Is there any way I can make it without extending TabActivity?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured it out.

In Xml file I should define TabHost like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mytabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
```

In Java file:

```
public class HelloTest extends Activity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        TabHost tabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(R.id.mytabhost);
        tabHost.setup();
```

Comment: But I found a problem. I can not capture onTabChanged event. Does anyone know how?

Comment: Got it. I have to add one line in Java code:         tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(this);